# Hibernate unexpected end of subtree error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

hi i'm trying to do a query with JpaRepository and it launches the error in the title, the query is the following:

```
@Query(value="SELECT NEW com.example.dto.NotifichaDTO("
            + "(select count(*) from ComunicazioneEntity where fkRisorsa = ?1 and dataVisone is null), "
            + "(select count(*) from richiestaAssenza where fkRisorsa = ?1 and statoRichiesta is null), "
            + "(select count(*) from ritiroAssenza RA, richiestaAssenza AE where RA.statoRitiro is null and RA.fkAssenza = AE.idRass and Ae.fkRisorsa = ?1), "
            + "(select count(*) from Documento where fkRisorsa = ?1 and dataFirma is null)"
            + ")"
             )
List<NotifichaDTO> getNotifiche(Long matricola)
```

what could the mistake be? I'm legit confused.
The names of the enities and field are all correct.
The app doesn't even startup it launches the error on boot not on execution.

The complete error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [SELECT NEW com.example.dto.NotifichaDTO ((select count(*) from com.example.demo.model.RichiestaAssenzaEntity where fkRisorsa = ?1 and statoRichiesta is null), (select count(*) from com.example.demo.model.RitiroRichiestaAssenzaEntity RA, com.example.demo.model.RichiestaAssenzaEntity AE where RA.statoRitiro is null and RA.fkAssenza = AE.idRass and AE.fkRisorsa = ?1), (select count(*) from com.example.demo.model.DocumentoEntity where fkRisorsa = ?1 and dataFirma is null))]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `SELECT NEW com.example.dto.NotifichaDTO(` - what each word in this part of SQL code must mean?

Comment: what do you mean? I need a list of NotifichaDTO objects, the constructor needs 4 integers, I wanted to have them all in the same query to save time and resources, so I did 4 subqueries

Comment: *I need a list of NotifichaDTO objects* There is no any NotifichaDTO object in MySQL. You must get 4 count values with a query, retrieve them from the rowset into some variables then call your constructor.

Comment: I don't think you know how jpaRepository works, I'm already calling the constructor in the query, each subquery returns an integer and takes the position of the method parameter

Comment: *I don't think you know how jpaRepository works* You're right. But I see that you don't know this too. Your explanations are absolutely impossible. *I'm already calling the constructor in the query* - you cannot, this is query text is incomprehensible nonsense from MySQL looking point. MySQL does not know about jpaRepository, its objects, methods, constructors.. it even does not know what (Java, PHP, console client, etc.) sends a query to it.. Your code looks like ```@Query(value="some string")``` - do you really think that this calls your constructor and provides needed parameters inot it?

Comment: I'm not supposed to write in sql, it's jpql, the language for non-native queries in jpaRepository, hybernate translate it in comprehensible sql when it actually needs to interrogate the database. Yes i'm sure it does that thing, or at least it would if it didn't have that error